# How do I specify the title of a scatter plot made in Google Tables?

Tags: google-drive

Users can now make "tables" in Google Drive by going to Create -> More -> Table (beta). I uploaded [my own data (tsv)](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1531353/CS171/hw3/raw_refined_data.tsv) and then made a scatter plot by going to Visualize -> Scatter.

How do I

1. add a title to my visualization?
2. add axes titles?

Answer (score 1):

This may have become possible, or at least much easier, since the Q was asked. Presently (New Google sheets) a default scatter plot may look like this:

[image: WA26899 first example]

Click on the down arrow at top right and select Advanced. Enter title of your choice where indicated:

[image: WA26899 second example]

and scroll down to enter the Horizontal axis title of choice (though there are several other ways to achieve the same result). Strangely, there was no default Vertical axis title, so right-click somewhere in the chart and in the pop-up select Axis, then  Left vertical axis title:

[image: WA26899 third example]